# NSOperationQueue and concurrent operation

Tags: ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, ios-4.2

As the `NSOperationQueue` Class Reference said:
In iOS, operation queues do not use `Grand Central Dispatch` to execute operations. They create separate threads for non-concurrent operations and launch concurrent operations from the current thread.

But I found in iOS 4.2.1,queue always create threads for concurrent or non-concurrent operations. And I think queue don't care concurrent or non-concurrent at all, because a breakpoint in isConcurrent never be broken. So I think the Reference was wrong...

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for NSOperation, you should see a note about Mac 10.6 (which roughly corresponds to iOS 4.0) ignoring isConcurrent.

Basically, the only reason to create a concurrent NSOperation would be if you were going to fire it manually.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` does use GCD. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> In iOS 4 and later, operation queues use Grand Central Dispatch to execute operations.